# How to properly write a machine learning algorithm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to machine learning, and I wanted to make a model that can predict a time series graph, and I keep getting errors. Is there something I am missing? I find out that I learn from getting reference code, then modifiying it, and learning over time what each component does.

```
""" Original Repository (Reference)
https://github.com/nicknochnack/Tensorflow-in-10-Minutes/blob/main/Tensorflow%20in%2010.ipynb
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('Marble & Slope Internal Data.csv')
x = pd.get_dummies(df['Distance Travelled(CM)'])
y = df['Height Off Ground(CM)']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2)
x_train.head()
y_train.head()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu',input_dim=25))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics='accuracy')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32)

myline = numpy.linspace(0, 100, 100)

plt.plot(myline, model.predict(myline),color='#ff8003',linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

Output from SHELL

```
Epoch 1/20

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9882 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
...

...
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/20
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 25) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_input'), name='dense_input', description="created by layer 'dense_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\___\OneDrive\Documents\Python\ALGA.py", line 30, in <module>
    plt.plot(myline, model.predict(myline),color='#ff8003',linewidth=3)
  File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file5t873kv5.py", line 15, in tf__predict_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1845, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1834, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1823, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1791, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential" (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Comment: Can you past a few lines of your data ?

Comment: Ok. This was from the CSV File
Height Off Ground(CM),Distance Travelled(CM)
4,61
5.3,87
7,97
10.2,110.7
14,124
17,247
20,291
23.5,346
27,373
30,381.1
33.5,419
30,392
9,185
9,182
9,180
13,274
13,273
13,274
16,330
16,326
16,328
19.5,413
19.5,419
19.5,405
23.5,477
23.5,473
23.5,478

Comment: I think `pd.get_dummies` is unnecessary for this data. Can you read the documentation for `pd.get_dummies1` ? Moreover the original example has many features.

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `x_train.shape` and `y_train.shape`?

Comment: This was also at the bottom of the shell 


         Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential" (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None

Comment: I Temporarily added extra code to print the shape of the model. 
shape of x_train:
(21, 25)
shape of y_train:
(21,)

Comment: The top error is this now:```WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 25) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 25), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_input'), name='dense_input', description="created by layer 'dense_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).```

Answer (score 0):

With the Kaggle dataset for Chronic Kidney Disease, I was able to duplicate the error. The shape mismatch was the cause of it.

To fix it, myline was reshaped as seen below.

```
model.predict(tf.reshape(myline,(1,25)))
```

Kindly refer to this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/4c48af5759b9a3a8d1a22c0321a6b9ea/untitled126.ipynb#scrollTo=dRp6dXJ5bZRY) for complete code. Thank you!